# What distribution for Golf strokes?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, underdispersion

I'm trying to find a distribution that adequately represents the number of strokes professional golfers make on a par 3 hole, so that I can simulate outcomes from this distribution.

I have been looking at count data distributions (such as poisson and negative binomial) and also at zero truncated distributions since it's impossible to complete the hole in 0 strokes.

Here is the bar plot of the Par 3 data for the 2016 PGA tour:

[image]

The closest I have been able to get is a zero truncated Negative Binomial with an alpha of 0 (which I understand is essentially a poisson):

[image]

It appears that my simulated shots are a lot more dispersed than the actual data so I believe I need to find a way to simulate under-dispersed and zero truncated count data.

I have so far been unable to find a way to do this in R. I have been using the `rztnbinom`and `rztpois` functions to simulate my golf strokes but from what I can tell they do not support underdispersion.

Does anyone know of a distribution  and/or R function I can use to model this outcome? Or even know of alternative routes for achieving these simulated results?

Comment: Simple: use the distribution displayed in your first graph: the *empirical distribution.*